# Does anyone know why my console wont stop printing inside my while loop?

Tags: java

```
package libraryhelp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainSystem {

    static String fileName = null;
    static Library lib = new Library();
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Boolean running = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(running) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter = for load a library."
                    + "\nEnter 1 for save and quit"
                    + "\nenter 2 for list all books in library"
                    + "\nEnter 3 for add book to library");
            int answer = in.nextInt();
            switch(answer) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Enter the file name to load);");
                loadScript(fileName);

                break;
            case 1:
                saveAndQuit();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println(lib.toString());
                break;
            case 3:
                addBook();
                break;
            }           
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

When I try to run my program it appears to just keep printing the system.out.println, does anyone know why this may be? I am following a tutorial on youtube and my code appears to be the same although could be a small detail which is causing this.

issue - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gtE9.jpg

SOLVED - it appears eclipse was to blame, despite restarting it already restarting it again seems to have done the trick.

Comment: `System.exit(0);` is VERY useless here // your while loop goes because running is true, you never set it to false, so it continue ^^

Comment: I've set it to false seems to be doing the same

Comment: When I say it keeps printing I mean repetitively, I want it to run but it is continuous

Comment: So it doesn't stop printing

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve], including _specifically_ what is happening and what you wanted to happen instead.  Your actual question is currently spread across (at least) 4 comments in addition to the question text itself.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked alex :(

Answer (score 1):

Because you are never changing `running` to `false`.

Somewhere in the switch block you will need to change the variable running to false.

```
running = false;
```

And only then the `while` loop will get terminated

Comment: I've explained it a bit badly, I want it to run but it keeps printing it over and over

Comment: It keeps printing what over and over?